# Is it possible to use animate with an attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the opacity of an element with jQuery (with a fade in animation):

```
$(`#pano-${index}`).animate({ 'opacity': 1})
```

But I don't get the result that I want:

```
<a-sky style="opacity: 1;"></a-sky>
```

I want to accomplish this:

```
<a-sky opacity: 1></a-sky>
```

Is it possible to do that with jQuery?

Note: this works ... but it doesn't have animation:       `$(#pano-${index}).attr('opacity', 1)`

Comment: @Tushar `${}` won't interpolate if I use quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starter for ten, you could do it with a timer loop...

```
var opacity = 0, // starting opacity
    step = 0.1, // step size
    target = 1, // target value
    time = 50; // delay in milliseconds
// start timer loop, and record it's index
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    // assuming your selector works, set opacity
    $(`#pano-${index}`).attr({opacity: opacity});
    // increment opacity by step size
    opacity += step;
    // if we reached our target value, stop the timer
    if(opacity >= target){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, time);
```

Comment: Hey it almost work. But sometimes I get this: `Uncaught TypeError: interval is not a function` and the function doesn't work anymore.

Comment: maybe you have a function called interval somewhere else in your code - try using a different variable name for the index, like `intervalNumber` for example.

Comment: btw - due to the ridiculous way floating point numbers are handled in javascript, `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1` turns out to be `0.30000000000000004`. In order to get values incrementing in tenths, you would have do do something ludicrous like: `opacity = (opacity * 10 + step * 10) / 10;`

Answer (score 1):

Is `$("#pano-${index}")` at opacity 0 (or any other than 1) before the animation?

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2z2ojyt/)